# llamar a una clase desde otra sin que ocurra un StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, poo, object

Saludos,

Tengo un programa dividido por paquetes e igualmente divido la lógica de la interfaz, estoy utilizando los modelos DAO y Factory.

Tengo unos métodos **Get** dentro de un **JFrame** -a esta le llamaré **Clase A**- que hacen referencias a campos de textos, accedo a estos métodos **Get** desde otra clase que tiene un método Guardar -a esta le llamaré **Clase B**-.

El problema surge porque creo una instancia de **Clase A** en la **Clase B** para acceder a los métodos **Get** del **JFrame** y guardar la información.

De igual modo creo una instancia de **Clase B** en la **Clase A** para llamar al método **Guardar** dentro de un botón.

Debido a que llamo recurrentemente a dos objetos se crea un error de dependencias circulares entre **A** y **B** llevándome a un **StackOverFlowError**.

Mi pregunta es: como puedo llamar a las dos clases sin que ocurra este error.

Comment: Hola David. Por favor provee el código de los constructores de ambas clases.

Comment: Tengo un **JFrame** en el que hay varios métodos getters para encapsular los campos, en otra clase tengo un método para guardar la información de esos campos, como es previsible tengo que crear una instancia de la clase donde tengo el método **Guardar** dentro de la clase del **JFrame** para llamar al método **Guardar** y tengo que crear otra instancia de la clase del **JFrame** para llamar los campos dentro del método **Guardar** de la otra clase, eso me esta produciendo un problema de dependencias circulares como dice @MitsuGarcía.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer tienes un problema de dependencias circulares. Por el tipo de error que tienes, `StackOverFlowError`, tal parece que tienes algo así:

```
public A() {
   b = new B();
}

public B() {
   a = new A();
}
```

Esto simplemente hace una recursión infinita de instanciamiento de A y B, por lo que te producirá un `StackOverFlowError`.

En lugar de constructores puedes utilizar **setters** para asociar objetos entre sí.

Comment: mmm, a que te refieres con eso, podrías darme un ejemplo, disculpa es que no tengo mucho tiempo programando y aún estoy aprendiendo sobre Java y sus paradigmas

Comment: A ver. Si tienes dos clases que tienen referencias una de la otra, y en ambas clases - en sus constructores - instancias dichas referencias, se producirá un ciclo infinito, porque new A() instancia a B y new B() instancia a A (nótese que siempre se llaman los constructores).

Para solventar esto, en lugar de inicializar por constructor, puedes hacer uso de setters, osea, los métodos setX que tienes comúnmente en tus clases. Otra alternativa es: `new B(this);` en el construtor de A. Al pasarle 'this' le estás pasando la referencia de la clase misma.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas una instancia mediante la palabra reservada `new` se llama al método constructor, por lo que si instancias la misma clase dentro del constructor generas un loop infinito.

El metodo constructor por defecto devuelve una instancia de clase por lo que no necesitas llamarlo nuevamente.

No me queda claro por que quieres crear un objeto de la misma clase que estas instanciando y guardarlo como un atributo, pero podrías usar la palabra reservada `this` para hacer referencia a la instancia creada.

```
Objeto v;

public Constructor() {
 this.v= this;   
}
```